# Cannot access to the table with pyspark in azure

Tags: sql, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I created a Databse with a table inside it in azure synaps which was an external table of sample azure data.

[image]

I run the code below to get access to the data in this table through pyspark

`df = spark.sql("select * FROM greentaxidb.dbo.taxitable")`

when I run the code above I get:

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: The namespace in session catalog must have exactly one name part: greentaxidb.dbo.taxitable`

Comment: I checked also the answeres here https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/1144 but there were no usefull information for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the data into dataframe with saveAsTable to run it in pyspark notebook.

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filename>', format='parquet')
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("testdb.test1")
```

--

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.sql("select * from testdb.test1")
display(df)
```

[image]

You can go through the links from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark) for more details.